# `cargo package` error: extern location for foo does not exist

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have very simple program [here](https://github.com/THeK3nger/CellularMaps-Rust). I was able to build this program with `cargo build` and, as you can see in the GitHub page, it also build correctly on Travis-CI.

However, the command `cargo package` fails with the error:

```
error: extern location for cellular_maps does not exist: D:\UserFolder\Code\CellularMaps-Rust\target/package/cellular_maps-0.0.3\target\debug\libcellular_maps-ae97300493a8edd3.rlib
src\main.rs:1:1: 1:28 error: can't find crate for `cellular_maps`
src\main.rs:1 extern crate cellular_maps;
```

I was able to publish this small library on crates.io with an older rust build. It is changed something or it is just a bug in cargo? (If you look close, you can see that there are mixed backslashes and slashes in the path.)

Rust version is

```
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (91bdf23f5 2015-03-09) (built 2015-03-09)
```

Cargo version is

```
cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (b27cd47 2015-03-07) (built 2015-03-09)
```

I'm working on a Windows machine.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1404 which was just fixed with https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/pull/1406

Comment: Yes, thank you Steve. I should have checked the bug tracker before asking this question. When I download a new nightly I have some problem understanding if it is a problem of mine or a bug in rust/Cargo :)

Comment: No worries! It's hard to find things in the tracker sometimes.